# Microsoft Edge Extension: will runtime.onInstalled fire when loading unpacked extensions?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a more complex call happening within the actual event but I cannot even get a simple alert to work.

I'm testing the following:

```
browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code has a syntax error

```
    browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
        alert("hi);
    });
```

change to

```
    browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
        alert("hi");
    });
```

Comment: I typed it in incorrectly when I made the post, my extension still does not handle oninstalled even with correct syntax.

Comment: i included the same code into my extension. it works. please make sure, you debug it using console.log instead of alert. and be sure you installed the extension correctly.

Comment: conversion tool kit
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-edge-extension-toolkit/9nblggh4txvb

Comment: How did you access the background console before installing the extension?

Comment: Moe, This event is fires when extension is being install on edge. so when you debug the background page then you will see the printed line in console log. microsoft have already shared the method to debug edge extension